# Products are not showing in opencart admin and front end

Tags: mysql, opencart

My problem is my products are not inserting in admin panel whenever I insert it says `You have modified products`, but the row didn't add neither show. Moreover when I add another product the below error appears.

**Error:**

```
Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error No: 1062
INSERT INTO oc_product_description SET product_id = '0'
```

It is working fine at local.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the database engine or anything similar?

Comment: OC version? Did you install some third party extension?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the live database (you said it works fine in local) has all the proper permissions. Sometimes the user can have read permissions but not write permissions.